# Form_Tag problem with posted value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my routes for a specific controller of my application are (i create them manually):

```
  scope :path => '/labor', :controller => :labor do
    get '/' => :index, :as => 'labor'
    post 'start/:work_hours' => :start, :as => 'start'
    post 'stop' => :stop, :as => 'stop'
  end
```

I'm creating a form_tag, but i'm having problems passing the posted value. My form currently is :

```
  <%= form_tag start_path do %>
    <%= select_tag :work_hours, options_for_select([ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" ], "1") %>
    <%= submit_tag "#{t 'labor.start_work'}" %> 
  <% end %>
```

I would expect that to work, but unluckily, it does not and i don't understand why. I actually get a routing error *No route matches {:controller=>"labor", :action=>"start"}*

Why is this happening and how can i fix it, so that the :work_hours is properly posted from the form ?

Comment: have you action `start` in your controller?

Comment: yes, with all the handling and stuff. The rspec tests also work fine on that action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can actually try

```
<%= form_for :start_labor do %>
    <%= select_tag :work_hours, options_for_select([ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" ], "1") %>
    <%= submit_tag "#{t 'labor.start_work'}" %> 
<% end %>
```

then update your data n controller iwith `params[:start_labor][:work_hours]`. That worked fine for me

Comment: i get a no route matches '/labor' when posting. Indeed, there is no such route. Is :start_labor pointing to the start_path ? This symbol looks a bit weird to me, but i may just not know that it can be used like that :)

Comment: Strat_labor creates a parameters hash like `start_labor => {work_hours => "something"}`, if you look in your console you'll see that. Actually this action should be a member in your routes. try to add `member do \n post 'start/:work_hours' => :start, :as => 'start' \n end`

Comment: And why dont use use `resources :labor`?

Comment: This is not a scaffold. I like to build my routes from scratch, in order to fully know what is happening. I would not need a match on the index action, since i'm not posting there at any time. member would not work here i think, it's for resources right ?

Comment: index action can be excluded via `:except => [:index]`. I guess, it is

Comment: The thing is, i don't really understand how to make start_path to post the work_hours, as it is supposed to.

Comment: I know that you can even do a :via => :post but the thing is that i don't want to use resources. I'd like to modify my routes in the way that will make it work through my start action.

Comment: And i also want to understand why this is happening :P

Comment: run `rake routes` and look has it created what you want. start_path may look like start_labor_path

Comment: It seems ok : start POST   /labor/start/:work_hours(.:format)                      {:controller=>"labor", :action=>"start"}

Comment: also, the spec works :   it "should come up with an error if work_hours not in 1-8" do
   post :start, :work_hours => 9
   flash[:error].should == I18n.t('error.invalid_post')
   response.should redirect_to labor_path 
  end